# Multithreading: Issue in allocating and blocking resources

Tags: java, multithreading

I have multiple resources - for the sake of understanding say 3 resources namely XResource, YResource and ZResource (Java classes - Runnables) who are able to do a certain Task. There is a List of Tasks which needs to be done in parallel among the 3 resources. I need the resources to be locked and if one of the resource is locked then the task should go to some other resource and if none of the resources are available then it should wait till one of the resource is available. I am currently trying to get a lock to a resource using a Semaphore but the thread gets assigned to one Runnable only and the other Runnables are always idle. I am very new to multithreading so I might be overlooking something obvious. I am using Java SE 1.6

Below is my code -

```
public class Test {
private final static Semaphore xResourceSphore = new Semaphore(1, true);
private final static Semaphore yResourceSphore = new Semaphore(1, true);
private final static Semaphore zResourceSphore = new Semaphore(1, true);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Task> listOfTasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
    Task task1 = new Task();
    Task task2 = new Task();
    Task task3 = new Task();
    Task task4 = new Task();
    Task task5 = new Task();
    Task task6 = new Task();
    Task task7 = new Task();
    Task task8 = new Task();
    Task task9 = new Task();


    listOfTasks.add(task1);
    listOfTasks.add(task2);
    listOfTasks.add(task3);
    listOfTasks.add(task4);
    listOfTasks.add(task5);
    listOfTasks.add(task6);
    listOfTasks.add(task7);
    listOfTasks.add(task8);
    listOfTasks.add(task9);

    //Runnables
    XResource xThread = new XResource();
    YResource yThread = new YResource();
    ZResource zThread = new ZResource();

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfTasks.size(); i++) {
            if (xResourceSphore.tryAcquire()) {
                try {
                    xThread.setTask(listOfTasks.get(i));
                    executorService.execute(xThread );
                } finally {
                    xResourceSphore.release();
                }
            }else if (yResourceSphore.tryAcquire()) {
                try {
                    yThread.setTask(listOfTasks.get(i));
                    executorService.execute(yThread );
                } finally {
                    yResourceSphore.release();
                }
            }else if (zResourceSphore.tryAcquire()) {
                try {
                    zThread.setTask(listOfTasks.get(i));
                    executorService.execute(zThread );
                } finally {
                    zResourceSphore.release();
                }
            }
    }
    executorService.shutdown();
}
}
```

Comment: CPU schedulers try to put all threads of one process on the same CPU so they can share cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the resource locking logic to the task which is run in another thread.

By doing the locking in the current thread, you are not waiting for the task to be performed before releasing the resource. The reason you are seeing the problem you are is that you are not waiting for the task to complete (or even start) before calling `setTask()` on the same resource.  This replaces the previous task set.

```
Queue<Resource> resources = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
resources.add(new XResource());
resources.add(new YResource());
resources.add(new ZResource());

ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(resources.size());
ThreadLocal<Resource> resourceToUse = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> resources.remove());

for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
    service.execute(() -> {
        Task task = new Task();
        resourceToUse.setTask(task);
    });
}
```

Comment: But then how do I assign my tasks to resources which are available? I am checking availability of resource through the tryAcquire() method of the Semaphore class. Is there another way?

Comment: Following your suggestion I passed the Semaphore within the runnable and released it after it finished execution. However I still faced the issue that I am unable to allocate all the tasks to the threads within the for loop. So I made a while(true) loop until one of the resource is available for a task. And then break the loop once the task has begun.

Your answer certainly helped even if I couldn't get a proper solution. Would have upvoted the answer if I had enough repo.

Comment: @Stacklin I would use a fixed side thread pool of three, then use a ThreadLocal in each thread so you have exactly 3 resources for your three threads.  At this point, the Thread Pool will allocate the next task to the next free thread and your resource allocation has been done for you.

Comment: @Stacklin see my updated answer.  I am using the task to thread resource allocation the ExecutorService already does.  This ensures no more then one thread will be using a resource at any moment.

Comment: I implemented ThreadLocal  as shown below.

`ThreadLocal<Resource> resourceToUse = new ThreadLocal<Resource>() {
    @ Override protected Resource initialValue() {
         return resources.remove();
     }
 };`
But 
I didn't get what you did  in the service.execute() call. 
Also won't the resourceToUse variable always contain a single object, in this case the initial value?

Comment: @Stacklin it will for that thread. each of the three threads have one resource.

Answer (score 0):

Following Peter Lawrey's suggestion I passed the Semaphore within the runnable and released it after it finished execution. However I still faced the issue that I am unable to allocate all the tasks to the threads within the for loop. So I made a while(true) loop until one of the resource is available for a task. Below is the code:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
for (int i = 0; i < listOfTasks.size(); i++) {
   while(true){
        if (xResourceSphore.tryAcquire()) {

                xThread.setTask(listOfTasks.get(i));
                xThread.setSemaphore(xResourceSphore);
                executorService.execute(xThread );
                break;

        }else if (yResourceSphore.tryAcquire()) {

                yThread.setTask(listOfTasks.get(i));
                yThread.setSemaphore(yResourceSphore);
                executorService.execute(yThread );
                break;

        }else if (zResourceSphore.tryAcquire()) {

                zThread.setTask(listOfTasks.get(i));
                zThread.setSemaphore(zResourceSphore);
                executorService.execute(zThread );
                break;               
        }
     }
  }
 executorService.shutdown();
```

I don't like this solution much because it cannot be extended if my resources are doing different types of tasks and hence if I need a particular resource for a particular kind of task , my other tasks would be waiting continuously till the particular task gets done. But for now couldn't get any other way. Even after so much of research!